# Microprofile JWT responding with 401 all the time

Tags: microprofile

I'm having an issue trying to get Microprofile JWT working for my REST resources.

I'm able to build a JWT so when decoded on jwt.ie it is

```
{
  "kid": "Oh1YDQopers_qYMU4zQCmAf0UsFVD5D0NmkFE79s2q0",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256"
}
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "sub": "user12",
  "upn": "user12",
  "groups": [
    "ADMIN",
    "USER"
  ],
  "jti": "a27582fc-21e2-4365-b485-ed7193606d8b",
  "iss": "http://www.testissuer.com",
  "exp": 1617226928,
  "iat": 1617219728
}
```

My Application class is annotated with

```
@LoginConfig(authMethod = "MP-JWT")
@DeclareRoles({"USER", "SUPERUSER", "ADMIN"})
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
```

Resource class is annotated with

```
@Path("/my")
@PermitAll
@RequestScoped
public class MyResource {
    @Inject
    @Claim(standard = Claims.groups)
    private Set<String> groups;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed("USER")
    public String getString() {
        if (groups != null) {
            return "groups.size(): " + groups.size();
        }
        else {
            return "groups is null";
        }
    }
}
```

The ear file which includes this war includes a META-INF/microprofile-config.properties file with entry:

```
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=http://www.testissuer.com
```

To test this I'm generating a fresh token and setting the Authorization header to the encoded JWT and calling GET /my which is returning a 401 response. Added Bearer before the encoded token makes no difference. The WWW-Authenticate header on the 401 response looks like it's looking for a Basic realm value.

If I take out the @RolesAllowed("USER") line then the response I get back is "groups is null" so it's like the injection is failing or cannot be mapped to the "groups" claim in the JWT.

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: What runtime are you in? Are you integrating JWT MicroProfile support within an existing project or creating a new project? Can you add all the steps followed with all the output? How are you triggering the HTTP requests?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Websphere Liberty 21.0.0.1. It is an existing project but the JWT aspect would be a new feature and if I can get it to function would be a retrofit. Steps would be as above with a Postman client and I'm calling the web service with annotations in deployed application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PermitAll annotation on resource class was wrong, using it prevents principal data from being injected. Fix was to use @DenyAll on class and @RolesAllowed or @PermitAll at method level.